# Casting down polymorphic pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, polymorphism

I have a `Shape` (abstract) base class that `Triangle` and `Square` inherit from.  Square has a method `Split` which returns an array of Shapes:

```
Shape** Square::Split(string direction, int times)
{
    if (direction == "diagonal" && times == 1)
    {
        numSplits = times;

        for (int i = 0; i < times +1; i++)
        {
            shapes[i] = new Triangle(side, side, sqrt(2) * side);
        }
    }
    else if (direction == "horizontal" || direction == "vertical")
    {
        double newSide = (double)side / 2;
        numSplits = times;
        for (int i = 0; i < times + 1; i++)
        {
            shapes[i] = new Rectangle(newSide, side);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //to do 
    }

    return shapes;
}
```

in my main method I have

```
Square* square= new Square(3);
Shape** shapeArray = square->Split("diagonal", 1);
shapeArray[0] = (Triangle*)shapeArray[0]; //contains no Triangle members
shapeArray[0]= dynamic_cast<Triangle*>(shapeArray[0]); //still no Triangle members
int triangleType = dynamic_cast<Triangle*>(shapeArray[0])->GetType(); //contains Triangle members
```

I assume this is an example of object slicing?  But I don't understand why I can't cast the first element in the array (which is a triangle) to a Triangle, but the last line allows me to reach into the `Triangle` class.

header for Square if needed

```
class Square :
    public Shape
{
public:
    Square();
    Square(string);
    Square(string, string);
    ~Square();
    Square(int);
    Square(string, int);

    virtual double Area();
    virtual void Save(string);
    virtual double Perimeter();
    Shape** Split(string direction,int);
private:
    string sName;
    string filePath;
    int side;
    double diagonal;
    int numSplits;
    Shape** shapes = new Shape*[numSplits];
};
```

Comment: Can u include the error that you get?

Comment: why don't you use `std::vector`?

Comment: @Manny there is no error, in the first two lines wit comments I just can't access any type information for Triangle, but in the third line, I can.

Comment: @Axalo because in the project I'm working on they aren't use.

Comment: @wootscootinboogie why?

Comment: @Axalo because it's 20 years old.

Comment: Since you haven't presented an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it's difficult to see what's going on with your code. The symptoms are that you are using memory that you shouldn't be using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Shape** shapeArray = square->Split("diagonal", 1);
shapeArray[0] = (Triangle*)shapeArray[0]; //contains no Triangle members
shapeArray[0]= dynamic_cast<Triangle*>(shapeArray[0]); //still no Triangle members
int triangleType = dynamic_cast<Triangle*>(shapeArray[0])->GetType();
```

> I assume this is an example of object slicing?

No it's not.  You're dealing with *pointers* to your shapes - slicing happens when you try to assign the *value* of a derived type into an instance of one of its base classes, for a start - the base class may not be big enough (i.e. had fewer data members, had less memory reserved/allocated for it, and secondly, the assignment code may or may not copy the derived class's pointer to the derived class Virtual Dispatch Table - if that's how your compiler's supporting polymorphism).  Slicing doesn't happen when you just manhandle pointers to objects (though if you then use the pointers to coordinate copying you can slice).

> But I don't understand why I can't cast the first element in the array (which is a triangle) to a Triangle, but the last line allows me to reach into the Triangle class.

Your attempted casts aren't doing anything useful.  They tell the compiler to treat the `Shape*` as a `Triangle*` momentarily, but then you assign that value back into a `Shape*` variable anyway, losing the `Triangle*` static type information you momentarily injected.

The final `dynamic_cast<>` differs in that you use the cast-to value directly ala `->GetType()` - while the compiler still considers the static type to be `Triangle` - instead of assigning it to the `Shape*` and having the static type "decay" back to `Shape*`.

Comment: So if I wanted to cast these Shapes to Triangles I should use 
`Triangle triangle = (Triangle&)shapeArray[0];`?  That compiles, but I'm honestly not sure why.

Comment: Consequently, that line causes the program to crash.

Comment: @wootscootinboogie If you want to cast, you use `if (Triangle* p = dynamic_cast<Triangle*>(shapeArray[0])) ...use p->xyz... else std::cerr << "cast failed - shapeArray[0] is not a Triangle\n";`.  Regarding your cast above that crashes: in `Triangle triangle = (Triangle&)shapeArray[0];` `shapeArray[0]` is still a `Shape*`, but you bind a `Triangle&` to the memory occupied by the pointer (note: *not* the memory to which the pointer points).  Of course that will crash.  Tip: use C++ casts - `dynamic_cast<>`, `static_cast` - not C casts like `(Triangle&)` that the compiler doesn't sanity check.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I have only been at C++ a month or so and the project I'm working on is legacy so looking there for examples doesn't always lead to best practices :)

Comment: @wootscootinboogie: sure - good luck!  If you do get time later, do try to clean it up to use `std::vector<>` - you'll learn something in the process and it'll be easier to understand and more trustworthy too.  Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I've put this in an answer due to length, but is not a full answer.

What do you expect from this code?

```
shapeArray[0] = (Triangle*)shapeArray[0]; //contains no Triangle members
shapeArray[0]= dynamic_cast<Triangle*>(shapeArray[0]); //still no Triangle members
```

The first line should:

1. Take the `Shape*` pointer in the first element of the array
2. Downcast it to a `Triangle*`

double p = shapeArray[0]->
 3. Assign back into to the first element of the array. This is of type `Shape*`, so requires an upcast, bringing it back to where you started.

The second line should:

1. Take the `Shape*` pointer in the first element of the array
2. Downcast it to a `Triangle*`, or return `nullptr` if it is not actually a `Triangle'.
3. Assign back into to the first element of the array. This is of type `Shape*`, so requires an upcast, bringing it back to where you started.

So in short, the first line does nothing and the seconds zeros the element if it is not a `Triangle`.

To see whether you really  have `Triangle*` in the array, add a line such as:

```
double perimeter = shapeArray[0]->Perimeter();
```

You can set a breakpoint or log message in the `Perimeter` method of `Triangle` to check it is being called.

Alternatively write:

```
Triangle* triangle = dynamic_cast<Triangle*>(shapeArray[0]);
```

Comment: OK, I was under the impression that casting worked like strings, e.g. x = x.replace(' ') is required to store the new value in the string, and x.replace(' ') doesn't change the value in x (coming from Java/C# world).

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be expecting pointers to somehow "remember" what type of pointer has been stored in them. Strongly typed languages don't work like that.

Once `Shape ** shapeArray;` is declared, it is, and will always be, a pointer to a pointer to a `Shape`.

The expression `shapeArray[0]` has the type `Shape *`. You can store a pointer to a `Shape` that happens to also be a `Triangle` in it, but the only thing the compiler and runtime can assume later about the object pointed to is that it's a `Shape` of some kind.

The expression `(Triangle*)shapeArray[0]` has the type `Triangle *`, as does the expression `dynamic_cast<Triangle*>(shapeArray[0])`.

As you've found, you can access `Triangle`'s members from any expression with the type `Triangle*`, but not from a `Shape*` because there's no way of telling *what kind* of `Shape` it might be.